# Change a:link background image on a:hover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the background image to for a link to change when the link is hovered over. Essentially, the hover image is a different colour, so I'm just trying to change the colour of an image (which is not possible in any way that I know, so I'll just swap the image).

The code to display the logo:

```html
<a href="/" id="logo"></a>
```

And the CSS:

```css
#logo {
position: absolute;
display: block;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
background: url('../img/logo.png') no-repeat;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
}

#logo a:hover {
background: url('../img/logo-blue.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Is there a better way for me to display the logo that would easier facilitate this hover?

Edit (added header CSS):

```css
#header {
height: 75px;
text-align: right;
position: relative;
}

#header h2 {
font-size: 2.5em;
font-weight: 400;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 0.1em;
padding-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: A css sprite.  Combine both images into one that has the logos side by side.  To style the hover you re position the background image with `background-position`.  This saves one http request.

Answer (score 0):

Change it from `#logo a:hover` to `#logo:hover`, because your `<a>` element *is* the `#logo` element.

Also, a few other tips:

- Indent your CSS to make it easier to tell properties apart from selectors and other rulesets.
- Keep your CSS-referenced images and other assets in the same directory as the stylesheet, that way you won't need relative URIs and it keeps everything together.
- Why are you using `position: absolute;` without a `top/right/bottom/left` property? What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ah! Very good point. The CSS is normally indented in my editor, just lost those indents when posting to this site.

I'm using `position:absolute` to keep my logo image and my title on aligned. The logo is aligned to the left and the title is aligned to the right. I've appended my question with the header CSS.